# Como utilizar las celdas de una matriz en SSRS Report?

Tags: reportviewer, ssrs

Hola estoy elaborando un reporte en Reporting Services. En dicho reporte genere una matriz la cual contiene tres campos que se generan de una columna(estatus) de una tabla de mi base de datos y de estos agregue un campo calculado con la suma de las tres columnas, ahora de estas cuatro columnas deseo cambiar su valor por su equivalente en porcentaje:

> ```
> Campo C: 4
> Campo E: 8
> Campo NA: 8
> Campo GrandTotal(CampoCalculado) : 20
> ```

Las columnas y campo calculado me gustaria que quedaran algo como lo siguiente:

> ```
> Campo C: 20% 
> Campo E: 40% 
> Campo NA: 40% 
> Campo GrandTotal(CampoCalculado) :100%
> ```

Como veran necesito un calculo el cual debera cambiar los valores aplicando la regla de 3 pero no se como hacerlo, no soy programador en .Net hasta ahora intente usar el set expression en cada celda con lo siguiente:

```
=(Sum(Fields!cuantos.Value)*100) / Sum(Fields!cuantos.Value)
```

Como veran esto me marca error, cabe mencionar que el valor de cada columna es la suma de mi columna linea y en el set expresion  en todas las columnas viene esto: Sum(Fields!cuantos.Value), por lo que no se como usar el valor de cada columna, les agradeceria mucho su apoyo con esto, Gracias

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 listo creo que ya acomode bien mi pregunta... no se si me puedas ayudar con el problema que tengo